# Self-study question

Tags: probability, self-study, variance, central-limit-theorem

I'm currently working on a self study worksheet. I understand most parts of the solution for part III, but I can't seem to make out how this comes about:

[image]

**QUESTION:**

[image]

**ANSWER:**

[image]

Comment: Please show actual attempts - show any working and clearly identify where your specific problems are. From the tag wiki:
• *Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If don't seem to be making a genuine attempt, your question might be voted down or closed.*
• *Ask about specific problems you have encountered in your initial efforts. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take @Glen_b's comment seriously.  It would help if you can be clearer about what you do not understand.

If you take a sample of size $2$ from that distribution, the only possible way to get a sample mean $> 4.3$ is if you either draw a $4$ and a $5$ (in which case the sample mean would be $4.5$), or two $5$s (in which case the sample mean would be $5$).  It seems like the probability would then be:
$$
P(\{4,5\}) + P(\{5,5\})
$$
The latter term is pretty obvious, but the first term is sneaky.  Imagine flipping a coin twice, you could get $\{H,H\}, \{T,T\}, {\rm or}\ \{H,T\}$.  That is, there are three possibilities.  This suggests that the probabilities are $1/3,\ 1/3,\ 1/3$, but we know that's wrong.  We know, for example, that the probability of getting two heads in a row is $1/4$, and the probability of getting a heads and a tails is $1/2$.  What we need to realize is that order matters.  There are two ways of getting a heads and a tails: getting a heads *on the first toss* and a tails *on the second toss*, and getting a tails on the first toss and a heads on the second toss.  Figuring out the probability associated with the first term above requires exactly the same line of reasoning.

In case the mathematical symbols are confusing, the $\cap$ ('cap'), and $\cup$ ('cup'), are [set theoretic symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation) that roughly translate to 'and', and 'or'.  That is, in English $P([X_1=5\cap X_2=4]\cup [X_1=4\cap X_2=5])$ could be read, "the probability that the first car has 5 passengers *and* the second car has 4 passengers, *or* that the first car has 4 passengers *and* the second car has 5 passengers".